# When is interning during done during compile time or run-time? The reason for such behaviour in code? Problems in BlueJ?

Tags: java, substring, behavior, string-interning

[image: Input is "12"][image: this will return true when u enter "12"][image: When you will enter "012" in this code it return false..]**Value of `string` is 12 .And 'string_input' store the input number
`string` is declared and initialized in the code
while string_input is inputed by the user during run-time**

## Case 1

```
string_5=string_input.substring(0);
System.out.println(string==string_5);
```

**when we input "12" it returns true**

## Case 2

```
string_5=string_input.substring(1);
System.out.println(string==string_5);
```

**and now when we input "012".. it returns false**

Why do this happen??? :/

Comment: "Why do this happen??? :/" - In the second case they are different Strings.

Comment: When you pass 0 to the substring method, it simply returns the current instance.

Comment: This is not the way to compare strings.....

Comment: @newboyhun I believe iamSiddharthYadav is intentially using same object equality (aka `==`) to test interning behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When is interning during done during compile time or run-time?

Interning is done at runtime, when you call String.intern().

However there is *another* process, called 'constant pooling', that happens at compile time. All string literals that are equal are reduced to a single entry in the object code for a class.

Comment: Is `String.intern()` automatically called by JVM? If yes, then at what occasion is it called?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the title question: Technically runtime only, as during compile time there is no `String` pool to intern into.

However, all string literals and constant-valued strings as defined in the source files are automatically interned when the program starts up, and additional strings can be interned using the `String#intern()` method.

Also, for future readers: OP's results appear to be an IDE quirk, out of all things. OP was originally entering input as a command line argument through BlueJ's custom `public static void main(String string_input)` main method signature. Apparently BlueJ does some shenanigans behind the scenes to make this match the `public static void main(String[] args)` signature required by the JLS, and apparently those shenanigans involve interning the input string at some point, leading to OP's results.

Edit for below answer: Looks like I made a minor reading mistake. While this answer somehow (sort of) works, it relies on the fact that `string == string_input`, which I cannot confirm until OP updates the question (which apparently cannot be done as the source code has been deleted).

The answer can be found in the source code for `String`:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

Notice the last line: if `beginIndex == 0`, the original `String` itself is returned. Thus, in Case 1, `string` is indeed pointing at the same object as `string_5`, and so `true` is printed.

However, if `beginIndex != 0`, a new `String` is created, and so `string` is no longer pointing at the same object as `string_5`, and so `false` is printed.